# inside .map() style "this" Compenent (React.js)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, object, this

I have mapped an array of objects and if I click on one of the elements I want to change that element's color to red (by adding a CSS class), but it always colors all of the elements red. I thought that React gets the context automatically? do I still need to use 'this'?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import './Map.css';

const Arr = [
  {
    id: "i1",
    item: "item-1",
  },
  {
    id: "i2",
    item: "item-2",
  },
  {
    id: "i3",
    item: "item-3",
  },
];

const ListElement = (props) => {
  return <li className={props.className} onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</li>;
};

const Map = () => {
  const [changedStyle, setChangedSTlye] = useState(false);
  const styleHandler = () => {
    changedStyle ? setChangedSTlye(false) : setChangedSTlye(true);
    console.log("clicked");
    console.log(changedStyle);
  };

  const List = Arr.map((l, index) => (
    <ListElement key={index} onClick={styleHandler} className={changedStyle ? 'map-selected' : ''}>
      {l.item}
    </ListElement>
  ));

  return List;
};

export default Map;
```

```css
.map-selected{color:red;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a flag to change the color . You need to maintain a list which will push the selected Item's index to the list if selected and pop it out if it is clicked again .

```
const Map = () => {
  const [ selectedItems , setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  const styleHandler = (itemIndex) => {
    if(selectedItems.includes(itemIndex))
    {
      setSelectedItems(prevSelectedItems => prevSelectedItems.filter((item) => item !== itemIndex))
    } else {
      setSelectedItems(prevSelectedItems => [...prevSelectedItems, itemIndex])
    }
  };

  const List = Arr.map((l, index) => (
    <ListElement key={index} onClick={() => styleHandler(index)} className={selectedItems.includes(index) ? 'map-selected' : ''}>
      {l.item}
    </ListElement>
  ));

  return List;
};
```

We are passing the `index` to the styleHandler . When clicked the item for the firstTime we are pushing the item's index in the state . If the same item is clicked for the second item then we are removing it from the state .

```
const styleHandler = (itemIndex) => {
    if(selectedItems.includes(itemIndex))
    {
      setSelectedItems(prevSelectedItems => prevSelectedItems.filter((item) => item !== itemIndex))
    } else {
      setSelectedItems(prevSelectedItems => [...prevSelectedItems, itemIndex])
    }
  };
```

when items index is present in the selectedItems we apply the style

```
className={selectedItems.includes(index) ? 'map-selected' : ''}
```

In this way there is no need to maintain an addition flag or modify your source data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shyam, this works perfectly for adding the CSS-class, but when I click the element again, it removes the CSS-class from a different element.

Comment: updated the answer , made a mistake in the filter it has to be `(item) => item !== itemIndex)`

Comment: You are an absolute hero, works like a charm now plus I understand the concept! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

#### The Problem

The problem here is `changedStyle` is a state variable. Therefore, it is not unique to the array element, rather it affects all of the elements since it is the state of the `react` component. You need `changedStyle` as a property in your elements.

#### A Solution

You need to have a `changedStyle` flag in your elements. You can change the element in the array when clicked using `onClick`. You will dynamically assign a class name based on the flag `l.changedStyle`. You want your array to be a state variable so that react component will re-render once it changes.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import './Map.css';

const Arr = [
  {
    id: "i1",
    item: "item-1",
    changedStyle: false
  },
  {
    id: "i2",
    item: "item-2",
    changedStyle: false
  },
  {
    id: "i3",
    item: "item-3",
    changedStyle: false
  },
];

const ListElement = (props) => {
  return <li className={props.className} onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</li>;
};

const Map = () => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState(Arr)
  const styleHandler = (index) => {
    const newArr = [...arr]
    const element = newArr[index]
    newArr.splice(index, 1, {...element, changedStyle: !element.changedStyle}
    setArr(arr)
  };

  const List = arr.map((l, index) => (
    <ListElement key={index} onClick={() => styleHandler(index)} className={l.changedStyle ? 'map-selected' : ''}>
      {l.item}
    </ListElement>
  ));

  return List;
};

export default Map;
```

#### A recommendation

If you have a unique `id` or `key` in your array elements, don't use `key={index}` in your jsx. Instead use `key={l.id}`

Comment: this involves an additional transformation of the sourceData where the user now needs to map through his source list and add a new key `changedStyle` for all its items .

Comment: That is correct. There are multiple ways to do this, your answer is probably better performance-wise.